# Efficiently calculate minutes and seconds for MM:ss formatted display from seconds, using OpenLaszlo / javascript?

Tags: javascript, openlaszlo

I'm currently using the following function which is based on an example from the web, it is called every second to display the current progress through a video stream.

Is there something I could do to make this more efficient?

```
function secondstominutes(secs){

var s;
if(secs > 60){
  var min = Math.floor(secs / 60);
  s = min < 10 ? "0" : "";
  s += min +":";
  secs = secs - min * 60;
} else {
  s = "00:";
}

if(secs < 10){
  s+= "0" + Math.floor(secs);
} else {
  s += Math.floor(secs);
}
return s;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function secondstominutes(secs)
{
   var mins = Math.floor(secs / 60);
   secs = secs % 60;

   return (mins < 10 ? "0" + mins : mins) 
          + ":"
          + (secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be a little simpler, and uses less Math.floor, local variables etc. Here mine proposition:

```
function secondstominutes(secs)
{
   return (Math.floor(secs/60))+":"+secs%60;
}
```

This will give result like:

0:1 for 1 sec
0:10 for 10 sec
1:1 for 61 sec

etc.

If you want spaces etc, it could be done like this:

```
function formatZero(number)
{
   return (number>9) ? number : "0"+number;
}

function secondstominutes(secs)
{
   return formatZero((Math.floor(secs/60)))+":"+formatZero(secs%60);
}
```

And this one is for obbsesive One-line function ppls ;)

```
function secondstominutes(secs)
{
   return ((arguments[1]=(Math.floor(secs/60)))<10?"0":"")+arguments[1]+":"+((arguments[2]=secs%60)<10?"0":"") + arguments[2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[bobwienholt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/24257/)s version is compact, fast and clear and it's very similar to the way I would have implemented it. For fun I did some profiling of a few different solutions and I found this to be a little faster, however it is not as clear and do an assignment semi hidden in a statement:

```
function secondstominutes(secs)
{
    var m = (secs / 60) | 0;

   return (m < 10 ? "0" + m : m) 
          + ":"
          + ( ( secs %= 60 ) < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs);
}
```

Explanation:

```
var m = (secs / 60) | 0;
```

Divide secs by 60 and binary "OR" the result with 0. The binary "OR" converts the value to an integer and by or-ing with 0 the integer part of the result is returned without modification. This is faster than calling *Math.floor()* but less clear. Since it is converted to an integer you limit the length of any movie to 2147483647 minutes ≈ 35791394 hours ≈ 1491308 days ≈ 4085 years.

```
( secs %= 60 )
```

This is the short form of doing *(secs = secs % 60)*. It divides the value of *secs* by 60 and assigns *secs* the reminder (example 61 % 60 = 1). By profiling I found that it was a little faster to put that computation inside the return statement instead of on a row of its own.

```
(m < 10 ? "0" + m : m)
```

This computes the first statement *m < 10* and if it is true the second statement is executed *"0" + m* else the third: *m*. In English: If *m* is less than 10 then a zero is added at the beginning else the value is returned as is.

Comment: I really appreciate the detailed explanation, but I've gone with Bob's as it is clearer to someone inheriting this code.

Thanks!

Comment: No problem, I expected that you would choose bobwienholt since it is fast and clear. I only did this for fun to see if there was some way that was faster. I'm happy that you liked the detailed explanation! Good luck!